# .htaccess RewriteRule for URL Shortener

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-shortener

I am trying to build a very basic URL shortening website. I used almost all of basixnick's coding in this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZnthmFQKlVY all 3 parts) but I'm having an issue.

When you enter a URL into the shortening inbox, for example www.google.com, you will get the corresponding shortened code. Then when you copy and paste the URL, let's say www.mysite.com/xyz123, it will redirect you to www.mysite.com/www.google.com instead of simply www.google.com.

.htaccess looks like this. Is there an issue with the RewriteRule?

```
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
</Files>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ ./load.php?code=$1
```

EDIT to question:

Here is my load.php file:

```
<?php
$code = $_GET['code'];

require("./connect.php");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE code='$code'");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

if ($numrows == 1) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $url = $row['url'];

    header("Location: $url");
}
else
    echo "No shortened url was found.";

mysql_close();

?>
```

When I remove the 'header(...)' code, and replace it with 'echo "$url";' the long url will be echoed just fine. So everything up to that point works fine. Maybe it's the 'header(...)' line. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Something's wrong with `load.php`, there's nothing wrong with the rewrite rule. It looks like the redirect code is redirecting to `/www.google.com` instead of `www.google.com`.

---

EDIT:

If the `$url` variable is literally `www.google.com`, then this is the problem. The browser is going to assume that `www.google.com` is a relative URI, and append it to the URL path that it used to make the request, `http://www.mysite.com/www.google.com`.

You either need to make it so the URL that you shorten include a protocol (e.g. `http://` or `https://`), or you make the protocol one or the other:

```
header("Location: http://$url");
```

Comment: I added an Edit to the bottom half of my question. Thanks for the input though. I didn't think anybody would respond so fast, so I appreciate any input.

Comment: I changed it to `header("Location: http://$url");` and it worked! wow. Thanks a lot. I'll have to keep it like that, or find a way to add `http://` or `https://` to the beginning of the $url in the database, if the user didn't add it already. Thanks.